# Java 7 update 45 broke my Web Start SWT application

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, java-web-start, jnlp

I maintain an Eclipse RCP application launched with WebStart. Java 7 u45 made some security changes, and now my application crashes on startup.

I've added to the manifest:

> Permissions: all-permissions
>
> Codebase: *
>
> Trusted-Library: true

This removed all of the warning messages from the Control Panel. But I still have a classloader issue when trying to load my IApplication implemenentation, probably the first of my classes to load. This is new to update 45.

Comment: Did you try launching your application from the commandline using "javaws application.jnlp". I am also facing a similar issue with update 45 and if i run my app from command line it launches fine, but not from the browser. And yes, both of them are using the same java version.

Comment: I have a similar problem: I use a quite old version of the equinox launcher. After signing the JNLP (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/signedJNLP.html), adding your manifest modifications and resigning my jars (also cf. https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/what_to_do_if_your), WebStartMain reads the JARs and finds the osgi framework, but cannot find the EclipseStarter class at invokeFramework. I guess it's the installLocation that is wrong. If you find a solution, please report here.

Comment: I already posted the solution below. Your problems are similar to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230773/java-7-update-25-makes-our-java-web-start-application-fail-with-no-logging.

Comment: I also have a similar problem, I have removed security warnings with the answer provided at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393826/java-applet-manifest-allow-all-caller-allowable-codebase, but my application still crashes on start-up. In Java WS Console I have set trace level to 5 and just before my application crashed I got these lines: network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:80/C:/configuration/config.ini, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/C:/configuration/config.ini with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting socket://localhost:80 with proxy=DIRECT

Comment: Do you see any error messages at your java debug console? What was your previous java version?

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced the same issue and managed to solve it by doing following:

**In all manifest files (for each JAR in your RCP project) add these attributes:**

```
Application-Name: My App Name
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: *
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Trusted-Library: true
```

Second part of solution is to **make jnlp properties secure by adding jnlp prefix**. I have found solution [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/552636/). You need to **do this for framework properties** (osgi, eclipse..) **and for your properties** E.g. instead of:

```
<property name="eclipse.product" value="com.amdosoft.oct.ui.product"/>
<property name="osgi.instance.area" value="@user.home/Application Data/myApp"/>
<property name="osgi.configuration.area" value="@user.home/Application Data/myApp"/>
<property name="my.App.property" value="someValue"/>
```

use

```
<property name="jnlp.eclipse.product" value="com.amdosoft.oct.ui.product"/>
<property name="jnlp.osgi.instance.area" value="@user.home/Application Data/myApp"/>
<property name="jnlp.osgi.configuration.area" value="@user.home/Application Data/myApp"/>
<property name="jnlp.my.App.property" value="someValue"/>
```

**Download eclipse launcher with sources from [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6/org.eclipse.equinox/launcher/1.1.0/)**

**In web start launcher you need to change back property names to old values** (without jnlp prefix). You can do that by adding this part of source into main method of WebStartLauncher class.

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
// copy properties to avoid ConcurrentModificationException
Properties copiedProperties = new Properties();
copiedProperties.putAll(properties);
Set<Object> keys = copiedProperties.keySet();
for (Object key : keys) {
    if (key instanceof String) {
        String keyString = (String) key;
        if (keyString.startsWith("jnlp.")) {
            // re set all properties starting with the jnlp-prefix 
            // and set them without the prefix
            String property = System.getProperty(keyString);
            String replacedKeyString = keyString.replaceFirst("jnlp.", "");

            System.setProperty(replacedKeyString, property);
        }
    }
}
```

**Export you new launcher as runnable JAR** and put it in the same directory where your JNLP file is located.

**Edit JNLP file** by adding this line:

```
<jar href="myAppLauncher.jar"/>
```

inside  tag and edit your application-desc tag like this:

```
<application-desc main-class="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WebStartMain">
  </application-desc>
```

Answer (score 0):

When 7u25 came out, my application would crash with a classloader issue (sometimes, it was weird). The fix involved nixing my "Components.jnlp" deployment strategy. I had my library files in a separate .jnlp (Components.jnlp, as per a solution I read online back in 2010) and my main .jnlp (launch.jnlp) would load that .jnlp.

Now, it seems the Netbeans-generated .jnlp is sufficient and I no longer need any separate .jnlp for library components. I'm not sure if eclipse gives you an auto-generated .jnlp or not.

In the end, changing the launch.jnlp involved me having to give my clients a new installer that would load the new .jnlp onto their computers. It sucked but it worked.

Also, I'm not sure what `Codebase: *` is supposed to do. Why don't you just put your actual codebase in there?

If you did not deploy your app with that approach then this answer probably won't help. Might help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

We've had multiple JNLP files up until now, and it seemed to work.

We install our app on customer internal networks, so we can't set a codebase other than * without resigning the entire set of jars for each customer.

Comment: Two things: 1) your "answer" looks like it should be a comment underneath my answer. 2) Wow, you deploy a separate .jar for the same program? Anyways, my point was: Oracle broke the contract for the JNLP ClassLoader. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230773/java-7-update-25-makes-our-java-web-start-application-fail-with-no-logging. It's a bug and Oracle has yet to fix it. I was just saying that MY way around was to undo my multiple-jnlp approach and go with the natural .jnlp that Netbeans generated for me.

Comment: My reference to the `Codebase: *` was really a side question. I don't think you'll need to touch anything related to the `Codebase` for your solution. I think you just need to undo the `Components.jnlp` strategy to avoid the NPE in the `ClassLoader`.