# What is the reason for java security pop up?

Tags: java, security, jar, applet

[image]

I am getting security pop up for java.

1 - Using **keyTool** library 
2 - **self signed** the jar file

Comment: The reason is written in the yellow box of your image. If it is your application I guess that you should show the relevant part of your code and/or explain what you did.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest in your JAR file does not contain the Permissions attribute - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451356) for details